# Why assigning new array to variable changes its reference not value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wondering why if I run this in JS, it will create new reference to the array, after I change its value:

```
var array = ["1","2","3"];
var copyOfArray = array;              
console.log(copyOfArray);  // ["1", "2", "3"]
var secondArray = ["2","3","4"];
array = secondArray;
console.log(array); //["2","3","4"]
console.log(copyOfArray); //["1", "2", "3"]
```

Why is reference to array not updated?

Comment: There is no pass-by-reference, only pass-by-value-of-a-reference. `array` is still the old array, it doesn't get overwritten just because you overwrite the copy, that's what happens when you assign something new to a variable, object or primitive

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: You've created two arrays and three variables. What exactly is the unexpected behaviour here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do :

```
var array = ["1","2","3"];
var copyOfArray = array;
```

That will create an array and make `copyOfArray` points to the same instance

> `array` --> instanceA
>   `copyOfArray` --> instanceA

Creating a second array will create a new instance while the first two ones are pointing to the old one :

```
var secondArray = ["2","3","4"];
```

> `array` --> instanceA
>   `copyOfArray` --> instanceA
>   `secondArray` --> instanceB

Now doing 
    array = secondArray;

Will update the reference that `array` points to, to the reference that `secondArray` points to so you will have

> `array` --> instanceB
>   `copyOfArray` --> instanceA
>   `secondArray` --> instanceB

That makes sense as you are pointing to the **reference** that `secondArray` **points to**, not to the `secondArray` itself

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ["1","2","3"];
```

and

```
var secondArray = ["2","3","4"];
```

both create completely new arrays.

After

```
var copyOfArray = array;
```

`copyOfArray` and `array` refer to the same array; `secondArray` refers to a *different* array.

When you now type

```
array = secondArray;
```

then `array` doesn’t refer to the first array anymore. Instead, it refers to the second array — to the same array `secondArray` refers to. `copyOfArray` still refers to the first array, because the variable hasn’t been changed. The reference of the array referred to as `secondArray` only gets passed on to `array`, not to `copyOfArray`.

In other words, after `array = secondArray;` the link between the first array and the variable `array` is *broken*. There’s no connection between the two anymore, and more importantly there’s no connection between `array` and `copyOfArray` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**Design**

The C language uses the dot operator `.` to access structure and union data members following an structure value identifier, but uses the `->` operator after a pointer to a structure in order to access its members.

Javascript adopted the `.` operator for simplicity of syntax when accessing object properties, but uses a pointer value when storing objects in variables and passing to functions. The value of the pointer, whether it be a memory address or index into a table of some kind used by the javascript engine, is inaccessible to javascript code.

**Documentation**

Javascript documentation typically states that all parameter data types are passed to functions by value. This is true only in the sense that object values in variables are a reference, and when passed to a function or set in another variable merely duplicate the object reference value without duplicating the object's data structure.

**Posted example**

```
var array = ["1","2","3"];
var copyOfArray = array;
```

leaves both array and copyOfArray holding references to the same Array object, whose location in memory is known only by the javascript engine.

```
var secondArray = ["2","3","4"];
array = secondArray;
```

creates another Array object with references to it set in secondArray and array. Storing the new reference in `array` overwrote the Array reference value already there. The reference value stored in copyOfArray however has not been changed.

So a log of `secondArray` shows  `["2","3","4"]` but leaves
`copyOfArray` holding `["1","2","3"]`